# "The key to design a poster" vs. "The key to designing a poster"

Tags: grammar, verbs, differences

I'm really confused as to which is more correct. The second sounds more natural to me, but I'm not entirely sure if I can explain why.

"The key to design a poster is to focus on good composition"

"The key to designing a poster is to focus on good composition."

Comment: Designing posters is fun. The key to designing them is [fill in the blank].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the word "to" can be used in a couple of different ways.

The usual way to form the infinitive of a verb is to put the particle "to" in front of it -- but that's not you want to do here (even though I just did it 3 times!).

> I want ***to design*** a poster. <-- not your situation

A key unlocks a particular lock, and you can use "for" or  "to" as a preposition to specify which one:

> I can't find the key to my front door.

This has evolved into a semi-idiomatic way of specifying the most important fact about figuring out something complicated, or learning some skill.

A prepositional phrase requires a noun, and one way to get a noun out of a verb is to use a gerund:

> ***The key to designing*** a good poster is focusing on good composition.

which is the usual way to say what you want to say. (Notice that, for parallel construction, I replaced the infinitive "to focus" with the gerund "focusing".)

You can use an infinitive to say this, but not with "the key", because "to" binds to it instead of the verb. One example:

> The best way ***to design*** a good poster is to focus on its composition.

Answer (score -1):

Couldn’t you say that because you are using the verb form it should be designs? Any word ending in “-ing” is not a verb.